# Using HTML in YML yields [Objcet Object] in js-yaml

Tags: javascript, yaml, remarkjs

I'm using HTML in YML yields [Object Object]

```
context:
      fieldLabel: |
                   <strong>
                       Some Bold Text
                   </strong> and now normal continued.
```

It's rendering as

```
context:
fieldLabel: ",[object Object], and now normal continued.↵"
```

but I want my output to be

```
context: { fieldLabel: '<strong>\n    Some Bold Text\n</strong> and now normal continued.\n' },
```

My JS Code :

```
const tests = YAML.safeLoad(this.props.children,{json:true});
console.log("tests",...tests)
```

Console output :

```
context:
fieldLabel: ",[object Object], and now normal continued.↵"
```

It is coming as [object Object] instead of `<strong>\n Some Bold Text\n</strong>`

Answer (score 2):

From the [js-yaml docs](https://github.com/nodeca/js-yaml#safeload-string---options-):

> **safeLoad (string [ , options ])**
>
> Recommended loading way. Parses string as single YAML document. Returns a JavaScript object or throws YAMLException on error. By default, does not support regexps, functions and undefined. This method is safe for untrusted data.

As you're including non-safe code (i.e. HTML) in your yaml, it looks like js-yaml is giving you an error instead. You can do a non-safe load with `load()` instead, if your yaml is guaranteed to be safe, or you could modify the structure of your code to change what's stored in yaml and what isn't.